# Client side validation for custom RequiredAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to build a custom RequiredAttribute for data validation that has a custom default error message.
So far I've got to:

```
public class MyRequiredAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    public MyRequiredAttribute()
    {
        this.ErrorMessage = "*";
    }
}
```

This one works but has no client side validation (gets always execute server side). So I got to:

```
public class MyRequiredAttribute : RequiredAttribute, IClientModelValidator
{
    public MyRequiredAttribute()
    {
        this.ErrorMessage = "*";
    }

    public void AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context)
    {
        // Note this is an empty method
    }
}
```

To my surprise, this one almost works: client side validation is back but the error message used client side reverts back to the original one, not my override.

Anyone can help me have the client side validation use the default error message I set in the constructor?

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the built-in `ErrorMessage` property of the `RequiredAttribute`?

Comment: Since the RequiredAttribute will be heavily used, all set to the very same generic error message, I wanted to get rid of repeating that every time.